# .htaccess mod_rewrite subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^new/?$ index.php?section=new
```

This works great and all, but I have recently implemented a subdomain `m.site.com` which reads off of a `/mobile` directory. When accessing `m.site.com/new` it will not display anything except return a server error. What can I do to correct this problem?

Basically, I want `http://m.site.com/new`

To achieve the same affect as `http://www.site.com/new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point `m.site.com` to `/` and then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# here i added [L] flag to stop rules matching
RewriteRule ^new/?$ index.php?section=new [L]

# everything that is not in new/* will still get redirected to the "old" mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /mobile/$1 [L,QSA]
```